# SQL Create a new table for frequent columns

Tags: sql

I'm designing a database and there are a few tables called Staff, Member, Supporter, etc. In each of these tables are columns: street, city, state, country, postal code. Should a separate table be created to handle all of these columns and be referenced from each of these tables since these columns appear so often? If so, how would I do that? Create an ID for each address so that I can get the correct address in the address table?

Answer (score 1):

The basic thing you are trying to pursue is called normalization and is generally a good thing.  You can read more about it here:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization.

I'm a fan of the phrase "Normalize until it hurts, denormalize until it works."  Do you NEED to do things like search all addresses and their associated records, regardless of type?  Need to find everyone at the same address whether they are a staff, a member, or a supporter?  These kinds of things are compelling reasons to normalize addresses into a single table.

But, do you need to treat an address as a first order entity, the way the post office would?   If you need them to be distinct, you may want to have multiple entities pointing to the same address.  But in that case you are talking a many-to-many relationship, which adds complexity and isn't necessarily desirable even though it is a more accurate "real world" model.  If you can live with some duplicate addresses pointed to by different relationships, or don't expect duplicates, you can save yourself that complexity.

You ARE asking a good question.  These things are situational, and if you are going to have a large complex system, you should think through the use cases for the data thoroughly and get help until you are confident enough not to be asking a simple question like this.

If you are just practicing or designing a relatively simple system, then you should probably normalize the data as described.  I would just have an "Address" table with an ID for each row.

Answer (score 0):

As of me, You need to create separate table for Address Detail. In Address Detail Add two columns for reference.

1. Master ID -> You define one unique Id for one Table. e.g. 1001 For Staff, 1002 For Members...etc.
2. Transaction ID -> if Any record inserted that ID, you link with this transaction ID.

Answer (score 0):

You could separate them as Person/Role. You would have a table of roles (i.e. staff, member, supporter, etc.) and a table of people (name, address, street, city, etc)

This gives you full relational control over both people and roles, including a history of when a person was a supporter, became a member, and was hired on as staff - of sorts.

Consider this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3826c/5/0

((forgive the fiddle, it's my first share of sqlfiddle. Without knowing your DB, I chose MySQL))

Comment: I forgot to mention having the joining table "PersonRoles" which assigns the personid and roleid to a unique index of PersonRoles. Couple this with the time stamp and viola!